# DynamoDB: create table with global index from cli - parameter validation failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create DynamoDB table with global index like this:

```
aws create-table \
--table-name test1 --attribute-definitions AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S AttributeName=consumerId,AttributeType=S \
--key-schema AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH \
--global-secondary-indexes IndexName=consumerIdInd,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=consumerId,KeyType=HASH}],Projection={ProjectionType=ALL}
```

This returns:

> Parameter validation failed:
> Invalid type for parameter GlobalSecondaryIndexes[0].KeySchema[0], value: AttributeName=consumerId, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
> Invalid type for parameter GlobalSecondaryIndexes[1].KeySchema[0], value: KeyType=HASH, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command does not have services name `dynamodb` then you need to wrap `--global-secondary-indexes` between double quotes.

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name test1 --attribute-definitions AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S AttributeName=consumerId,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH --global-secondary-indexes "IndexName=consumerIdInd,KeySchema=[{AttributeName=consumerId,KeyType=HASH}],Projection={ProjectionType=ALL}" --billing-mode PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

> tested it works